# Moving breakpoint in middle of debug session with VSCode

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

I am from Visual Studio land mostly working with C# applications. Recently switched to VSCode and it has been a . good experience so far. However, I miss a particular feature from that Visual studio has but I don't VsCode does have or at least I do not know how to.

With Visual Studio, I could move control from where it currently is to any previous position by physically clicking it and dragging it to a previous position. However, I do not seem to have that option with Visual Studio Code. Is there any way for me to enable that feature in VS Code for C#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe still an open issue.
https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/1025